# I have a question about how to apply FirebaseAnalytics.SetConsent

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am developing with Unity.
Recently, I was informed that I need to apply consent mode in Firebase Analytics.
I checked the related guide, but I couldn't find a guide for Unity, so I don't know if I applied it correctly.

Write down the implemented code as well.
According to the guide, when the implementation is done correctly:
'ConsentSettings: adStorage=granted, analyticsStorage=granted'
They say I need to check these logs, but I don't see them.

I would like to know if I did something wrong or if I am missing something.

Thank you in advance.

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android&hl=ko#kotlin

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)

// Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
// where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
Crashlytics will use the DefaultInstance, as well;
this ensures that Crashlytics is initialized.
Firebase.FirebaseApp app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

Set a flag here for indicating that your project is ready to use Firebase.

var FC_Consent = new Dictionary<ConsentType, ConsentStatus>();
FC_Consent.Add(ConsentType.AnalyticsStorage, ConsentStatus.Granted);
FC_Consent.Add(ConsentType.AdStorage, ConsentStatus.Granted);

FirebaseAnalytics.SetConsent(FC_Consent);
FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
}
else
{
UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
// Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
}
});
```

I tried to implement it according to the guide and expected the results that the guide said.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Recently, I received an 'Ads personalization consent signal not detected' message in the data stream of Google Analytics page property settings and a notification that action was required.

Comment: I confirmed that the following link is available for information related to this.
'https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android&sjid=8552446487099886181-AP&consentmode=advanced'

I am developing with Unity, so I tried to apply this content to Unity.
The link states that if the application is successful, a 'Setting consent' message will be displayed in the log, but I was unable to confirm.
I want to know if I did something wrong.

If you have any additional questions, please leave a reply.